# Gunicorn working from command but not from service

Tags: websocket, gunicorn

When i execute direct on terminal

> /ins/icenv/bin/gunicorn app.main:app --workers 1 --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --certfile=/ins/key_ls/fullchain.pem --keyfile=/ins/key_ls/privkey.pem --access-logfile /tmp/null --error-logfile /ins/logs/error_log_gunicorn_ws.log &

gunicorn work perfectly and I receive data from port 8000 but when I run

> sudo systemctl start gunicornws

process start and status is active but connection to port 8000 return no data

Here is my gunicornws.service

```
Description=WebSocket Gunicorn Service
After=network.target

[Service]
User=customuser
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/instant_connection/
ExecStart=/ins/icenv/bin/gunicorn app.main:app --workers 1 --worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --certfile=/ins/key_ls/fullchain.pem --keyfile=/ins/key_ls/privkey.pem --access-logfile /tmp/null --error-logfile /ins/logs/error_log_gunicorn_ws.log

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I already tried many settings but I can't find any logical reasons for this.

I will appreciate your support.

> > NOTE: I have another instance of gunicorn running on .sock and work perfectly with nginx but I need another for WebSockets and a port for internal reasons.

EDIT.
I change my gunicornws.service to and it's running perfectly

```
Description=WebSocket Gunicorn Service
After=network.target

[Service]
User=jean15151352
Group=jean15151352
WorkingDirectory=/ins/
ExecStart=/ins/icenv/bin/gunicorn \
 app.main:app \
--workers 1 \
--worker-class uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker \
--bind 0.0.0.0:8000 \
--certfile=/ins/key_ls/fullchain.pem \
--keyfile=/ins/key_ls/privkey.pem \
--access-logfile /tmp/null \
--error-logfile /ins/logs/error_log_gunicorn_ws.log

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: You're running the command as a different user|group. Have you confirmed that the user|group is able to access `gunicorn`, the `/ins` subfolders? You state but don't demonstrate that the service binds to the port. You don't include the state of the `systemctl` service nor the service's logs. These would help you and us.

Comment: Your question is tagged with `nginx`, `google-cloud-platform` and `websocket` but makes no reference to these technologies. Tags define your audience. I encourage you to use the minimal set of tags that is relevant to your question.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the tags list and edited the post with the solution, your help was really helpful.

Comment: I'm pleased to hear it. You can use the "Your Answer" section to answer your own questions. It's encouraged rather than updating the question.

Comment: This could be of help https://youtu.be/Dh5lzOwyVAY?t=1025 to Run FastAPI on Gunicorn as a Systemd Managed Unit Service. A more organised way by using gunicorn.py with all its relevant settings.